# Swift: Setting UIImage as Background

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, uicolor

My line in viewDidLoad() is complaining about not having an ! in the following statement:

```
 view.backgroundColor = UIColor.colorWithPatternImage(UIImage(named: "background.jpg"))
```

However, when I change it to this as suggested:

```
 view.backgroundColor = UIColor.colorWithPatternImage(UIImage(named: "background.jpg")!)
```

It gives the following error:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Again, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does `background.jpg` definitely exist?

Comment: It does. I added it to the library this time. I think you may have seen my previous post. XD

Comment: And tried it without the .jpg expression. Still didn't work.

Comment: "I added it to the library this time" The _library_? What do you imagine _that_ means? You need to add it to the _project_.

Comment: I'm sorry, that is what I meant. It is under my project folder.

Comment: It must also be _part of the app target_. Otherwise it is not copied into the bundle of the app.

Comment: See the discussion in my book on how to add an image or other resource to your app: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch06.html#_other_resources

Comment: And see also here: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch06.html#_build_phases If you don't see your image in the Copy Bundle Resources build phase, it is not being copied into the app.

Comment: Thanks matt for your assistance! I was able to resolve it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change your code to this:

```
if let image = UIImage(named: "background.jpg") {
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.colorWithPatternImage(image)
} else {
    println("There was no such image as background.jpg")
}
```

That way you won't crash, and the `println` will log to console and prove to you that the image doesn't exist - until it does, of course.

Comment: Have to +1 this really hard.  This answer won't suddenly make `UIImage(named: "background.jpg")` return non-nil, but it does eliminate the extraordinarily bad pattern of just throwing `!` in here, there, and everywhere to get rid of compile errors that people can't manage to understand for whatever reason.